# Disabling HTTPS host authentication in TortoiseHG for internal self-signed certificates

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, tortoisehg-2.0

How do you disable HTTPS host authentication in TortoiseHG for internal self-signed certificates. For internal servers HTTPS is primarily used for encryption.

The TortoiseHG documentation says that it is possible to disable host verification (i.e. verification against the Certificate Authority chain) [here](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/sync.html#host-authentication) but I can't seem to find the option.

Its supposed to be an option when cloning a remote repository. I am using the latest TortoiseHG 2.0.5

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the TortoiseHG Workbench, in the Sync tab (or in the Sync screen), if you have a remote path selected, you should see a button with a lock icon on it:

[image]

That will bring up the Security window, where you can select the option `No host validation, but still encrypted`, among other settings. When you turn that on, it adds something like this to your `mercurial.ini`:

```
[insecurehosts]
bitbucket.org = 1
```

That's machine-level config for TortoiseHg, but it doesn't seem to affect the Clone window.

On the command-line, you can use `--insecure` to skip verifying certificates:

```
hg clone --insecure https://hostname.org/user/repository repository-clone
```

This will spit out a number of warnings about not verifying the certificate, and will also show you the host fingerprint in each message, like the example warning below (formatted from the original for readability):

```
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 
 24:9c:45:8b:9c:aa:ba:55:4e:01:6d:58:ff:e4:28:7d:2a:14:ae:3b not verified
 (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
```

A better option, however, is [host fingerprints](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hostfingerprints), which are used by both `hg` and TortoiseHg. In TortoiseHg's Security window, above `No host validation` is the option `Verify with stored host fingerprint`. The Query button retrieves the fingerprint of the host's certificate and stores it in `mercurial.ini`:

```
[hostfingerprints]
bitbucket.org = 81:2b:08:90:dc:d3:71:ee:e0:7c:b4:75:ce:9b:6c:48:94:56:a1:fe
```

This should skip actual verification of the certificate because you are declaring that you already trust the certificate.

[This documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates#Self-signed_certificates) on certificates may help, as well.

Comment: Thanks for that. What is not clear though is how to do it during cloning. Before being able to synchronise you first need to clone it also with the same settings, or the error occurs. Is there a way to do it during clone?

Comment: Just found out that cloning without Host validation is not yet possible through TortoiseHG. However the feature is on the way and already in the unstable release 2.0.5516.4529, so anyone needing this will need to use that version for now until it is released in the stable version. More details here: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/718/no-insecure-option-when-cloning-a

Comment: Saw your first commented and worked for a while on adding more.

Comment: Thanks about the Host Fingerprint tip. The problem is that in the clone dialog that option is not available (not even in the latest unstable release) while the 'Do not verify host certificates' is. (Maybe I should add it as a request in the issue list of TortoiseHG.)

Comment: The dialog may not have it yet, but I think if you have the host fingerprint already in your global config, cloning will use that instead of verifying the certificate. Don't know of any hosts using self-signed certificates, so I haven't tried it out.

Comment: @JoelBFant How would I know then the host fingerprint, it just throws error with no indication to any kind of fingerprints

Comment: @securecurve: Please read the answer again, paying particular attention to the paragraph that contains the phrase "Query button retrieves the fingerprint".

Comment: Thank you Joe for your answer. I'm talking about the command line hg tool, how would I do this?

Comment: @securecurve: How about the paragraph right above that? If you use `hg clone --insecure`, it gives you several certificate warnings and displays the fingerprint in the message. From there you can copy it and edit your `[hostfingerprints]` config section.

Answer (score 1):

In the Clone Repository window expand options and check "Do not verify host certificate" check box.