# Get certificate fingerprint of HTTPS server on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, mercurial, certificate, ssl-certificate, google-code

Recently Mercurial has added certificate validation when connecting to HTTPS servers. I'm trying to clone the wiki repository for a Google Code project at https://wiki.droidweight.googlecode.com/hg/, but the certificate is for `*.googlecode.com`.

Google Code's certificate does not cover multiple subdomains like `*.*.googlecode.com`.

I'm getting the error:

```
% hg clone --verbose https://wiki.droidweight.googlecode.com/hg/ -- C:\workspace\wiki
abort: wiki.droidweight.googlecode.com certificate error: certificate is for *.googlecode.com, googlecode.com, *.codespot.com, *.googlesource.com, googlesource.com (use --insecure to connect insecurely)
```

I need to get the certificate fingerprint. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164804/get-certificate-fingerprint-of-https-server-from-command-line/5165073#5165073) says how to do it on *nix.

**How would one get the fingerprint on Windows 7 (Home Premium)?**

References:

- [Open issue on Google Code's support site](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=4533).
- [Mercurial CA Certificates FAQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates#Host_certificate_fingerprints).

Comment: Since you're using TortoiseHg, [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293167/disabling-https-host-authentication-in-tortoisehg-for-internal-self-signed-certif) will help, as there's a place in the UI for querying the fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Mercurial are you using? 1.8.2 prints the fingerprint when you clone, [as per the documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates#Host_certificate_fingerprints).

**EDIT:** After some testing, I realised that Mercurial prints the certificate when you connect insecurely (I don't have `web.cacerts` configured, so cloning always succeeded, though with a warning). So if you pass `--insecure` to your `hg clone`, you'll get a clone and a fingerprint.

Alternatively, install [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)! It makes the Windows command line a fun place to be :) (I have no affiliation with GnuWin32; just hugely appreciative.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using mercurial 1.8.4 (the one bundled with TortoiseHg 2.0.5). I'll test and, if it works, mark the question answered.