# Configure Mercurial To Accept Self signed Certificates

Tags: iis-7, mercurial, ssl-certificate

How can we configure mercurial to accept self signed certificates . I have created a certificate and assigned it using IIS. I can brows my repository through a web browser after accepting the certificate error. But if I use command line (`hg clone https://server/hg/repositoryName`) to get a clone of the repository it says In Certificate verification failed.
How can I configure mercurial to accept that certificate ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling HTTPS host authentication in TortoiseHG for internal self-signed certificates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293167/disabling-https-host-authentication-in-tortoisehg-for-internal-self-signed-certif)

Answer (score 3):

use hostfingerprints hg.ini section, e.g.

```
[hostfingerprints]
hg.example.com = 2f:47:d5:d4:c8:28:34:b2:65:15:9b:15:ad:1e:11:b1:9e:8d:bb:cc
```

Comment: Do you mean the mercurial.ini file in user folder ?

Comment: +1 as this looks like it can be set at the user (hg.ini) or repository (.hg\hgrc) level.

Comment: I have edited mercurial.ini file as you said but still the same

Comment: @Jayantha: I use it with my global mercurial ini that I keep in my home directory. Did you use proper certificate fingerprint?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it, but on the Mercurial wiki is a section on [CA Certificates](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates#Windows).

It appears that you need to add a reference to your certificate file in the main `web.cacerts` file, which is referenced from `hgrc.d\paths.rc`.

Comment: I have saved certificate file as a .cer file and changed path.rc like this                                                                            [web]                                                cacerts=C:\temp2\cert.cer    Still not working

Comment: Looking at the link I sent, there seems to be an issue with IIS7 and OpenSSL (as used by Mercurial). Details are in the link.

Comment: I'll try with OpenSSL then :(. Thanks for the support.